# How to use random_split with percentage split (sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset)

Tags: pytorch, dataset

I tried to use `torch.utils.data.random_split` as follows:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split

list_dataset = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
dataset = DataLoader(list_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

random_split(dataset, [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(123))
```

However, when I tried this, I got the error `raise ValueError("Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!")`

I looked at [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split) and it seems like I should be able to pass in decimals that sum to 1, but clearly it's not working.

I also Googled this error and the closest thing that comes up is [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/67740).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're likely using an older version of PyTorch, such as Pytorch 1.10, which [does not have this functionality](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split).

To replicate this functionality in the older version, you can just copy the source code of the newer version:

```py
import math
from torch import default_generator, randperm
from torch._utils import _accumulate
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Subset

def random_split(dataset, lengths,
                 generator=default_generator):
    r"""
    Randomly split a dataset into non-overlapping new datasets of given lengths.

    If a list of fractions that sum up to 1 is given,
    the lengths will be computed automatically as
    floor(frac * len(dataset)) for each fraction provided.

    After computing the lengths, if there are any remainders, 1 count will be
    distributed in round-robin fashion to the lengths
    until there are no remainders left.

    Optionally fix the generator for reproducible results, e.g.:

    >>> random_split(range(10), [3, 7], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))
    >>> random_split(range(30), [0.3, 0.3, 0.4], generator=torch.Generator(
    ...   ).manual_seed(42))

    Args:
        dataset (Dataset): Dataset to be split
        lengths (sequence): lengths or fractions of splits to be produced
        generator (Generator): Generator used for the random permutation.
    """
    if math.isclose(sum(lengths), 1) and sum(lengths) <= 1:
        subset_lengths: List[int] = []
        for i, frac in enumerate(lengths):
            if frac < 0 or frac > 1:
                raise ValueError(f"Fraction at index {i} is not between 0 and 1")
            n_items_in_split = int(
                math.floor(len(dataset) * frac)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
            )
            subset_lengths.append(n_items_in_split)
        remainder = len(dataset) - sum(subset_lengths)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
        # add 1 to all the lengths in round-robin fashion until the remainder is 0
        for i in range(remainder):
            idx_to_add_at = i % len(subset_lengths)
            subset_lengths[idx_to_add_at] += 1
        lengths = subset_lengths
        for i, length in enumerate(lengths):
            if length == 0:
                warnings.warn(f"Length of split at index {i} is 0. "
                              f"This might result in an empty dataset.")

    # Cannot verify that dataset is Sized
    if sum(lengths) != len(dataset):    # type: ignore[arg-type]
        raise ValueError("Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!")

    indices = randperm(sum(lengths), generator=generator).tolist()  # type: ignore[call-overload]
    return [Subset(dataset, indices[offset - length : offset]) for offset, length in zip(_accumulate(lengths), lengths)]
```

Comment: Far as I can tell, this wasn't introduced until 1.13. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of your dataset, ie, it has the **len** method,

```
proportions = [.75, .10, .15]
lengths = [int(p * len(dataset)) for p in proportions]
lengths[-1] = len(dataset) - sum(lengths[:-1])
tr_dataset, vl_dataset, ts_dataset = random_split(dataset, lengths)
```